# Redirect all php requests to index.php via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have run into a small problem. Upfront, I am not experienced with .htaccess what so ever.

I am trying to implement pretty links. So I want **all PHP content** to be directed to index.php, which will handle all the content displaying etc. After fiddling and googling around, I have come to this setup:

```
# directs all content to index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hotel/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . /hotel/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*"hotel" exists because I am running wampserver and it sees it weird.*

It does what I am expecting, redirecting all the content to index.php. And that is the problem, that it is redirecting everything. I do not wish CSS, image, js, etc files to be touched. Only PHP files.

So, if someone enters /dir/foo/bar/, it redirects it to index.php.
If it is calling for say /dir/foo/style.css,  it leaves it alone and serves it.

P.S. I initially tried a bit different way. However, I ran in a problem that, if I called pretty link such as "/dir/rooms/", and there was a file called dir/rooms.php, it would load it. This is not what I was expecting.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hotel/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /hotel/index.php [L]
```

Comment: The docu: `https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html` say the syntax is : `RewriteRule pattern target [Flag1,Flag2,Flag3]` so you can write something like this `RewriteRule "^(.*)\.php$" /hotel/index.php [L]` to filter out only php been redirected

Comment: _“if I called pretty link such as "/dir/rooms/", and there was a file called dir/rooms.php, it would load it”_ - then try and disable `MultiViews`, that is usually the feature that interferes in this kind of situation.

Comment: @CBroe Interesting, for now it seems to have worker. Thanks!